# Only one media query is being applied. Only the last media query is getting applied finally

Tags: html, css

Whenever the multiple media queries are being used, only the bottom most one (last query) is being applied while there are other  queries mentioned with their respective breakpoints / % of widths.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){
.col-lg-4{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid white;

    }
}
.col-lg-4{
width: 33%;
height: auto;
}

@media  (min-width: 850px) and (max-width: 1199px){
    .col-md-6{
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid white;
    }
}
.col-md-6{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 850px){
    .col-sm-12{
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid white;
    }
}
.col-sm-12{
    width: 100%
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: I think, it should be like this: @media screen and (max-width: 600px)

Comment: Is the word 'screen' mandatory?